# Odd behavior in Mongoid: after_add callback fired when accessing referenced model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, sinatra, mongoid

The model's callback is being fired after accessing a referenced document. It is odd behavior and I am not sure why this happens.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
class Group
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps

    belongs_to :domain_group, :class_name => 'Domain', :inverse_of => :child_groups

    field :name
end

class Domain < Group

    has_many :child_groups, :class_name => 'Group', :inverse_of => :domain_group, after_add: :print_childgroup

    field :sid

    def print_childgroup(group)
        puts 'calling print_childgroup()'
    end
end
```

Route handling:

```
get "/temp_init" do
    d = Domain.create(name: 'Domain', sid: '23Asdfai9')
    Group.create(name: 'group1', domain_group: d)
    Group.create(name: 'group2', domain_group: d)
end

get "/view" do
    g = Group.where(name: 'group1').first
    d = g.domain_group
end
```

To see it in action:

- Visit `/temp_init` to create seed values and console shows:

  ```
  calling print_childgroup()
  calling print_childgroup()
  ```

  This is expected since we've just added two groups, so the `after_add` callback is fired twice.
- Visit `/view` and the console output will show:

  ```
  calling print_childgroup()
  ```

  **This is NOT expected**

  The offending line is `g.domain_group`, which triggers the `after_add` callback for some reason.

My current workaround is this:

```
# Grab the domain group id
d_id = g.domain_group_id

d = Domain.find(d_id)
# Do stuff with d object
```

Which works, but it is ugly and seems like it is making an extra query. Why does `g.domain_group` fire the add callback and is there a proper workaround?